# Gimp - how to make entire layer transparent

Tags: gimp, transparency

I'm trying to create watermark so I want my logo layer to be transparent. How do I achieve this? I tried all the existing guides but they aren't working. The layers are in JPG format by default when I import them. Can someone give me the step by step directions?

Answer (score 4):

1. Drag general picture to a empty Gimp window or open it from File dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).
2. Drag second picture (watermark) to already opened image document or **Open as Layers..** from File dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>). Now you will see 2 layers in Layer tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). Make sure than watermark image is above of layer of general image.
3. Right click on watermark layer and select **Edit Layer Attributes..**.
4. In **Layer Attributes** set **Opacity** to 20-25 or smaller.
5. Optional: move your watermark layer or duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no transparency support in the JPG format. When you open a JPG in Gimp (and in Gimp 2.10, when use `File>Open as layers`), the layer has no alpha-channel, which is how you control transparency of pixels. This is easily checked, when there is no alpha-channel on a layer:

- the layer name is in **boldface** in the Layers list
- the menu `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel` is not grayed out (when that mayer is active).

To add an alpha channel, you of course use `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel`.